# Reporting Services Connect a Report to Multiple Databases

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2000

I have a report which I would like to have talk to different data sources on different database servers depending on some runtime parameters. Is there any way to set the report connection string on a run by run basis? I'm trying to avoid using a data processing extension but it a thin one to proxy the query seems to be the only way to do it.

**Edit**
There is a feature is called expression based query strings it did not appear until the SQL server 2005 version of reporting services. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2006/07/20/673051.aspx One version too late for me.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most powerful features of Reporting Services is that everything is an expression - including the SQL for your dataset. This means you can build your SQL expression from scratch.

We have a table of databases representing different snapshots of our data with a description and the database name. This is used as the query to populate a parameter the user can select from and then the database name is inserted into the SQL, so your dataset expression looks like this:

```
="SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 "
&"FROM " & Parameters!Database.Value & ".dbo.MyTable "
```

Then when you need to add another database for the user to select from, you just add it to the table of database names and all reports immediately have access to that data.

With servers it should be similar, something like:

```
="SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 "
&"FROM " & Parameters!Server.Value & "." & Parameters!Database.Value & ".dbo.MyTable "
```

You may need to set up the server that you are targeting as a linked server on the server that has the database that the dataset is connected to originally.

Comment: "...set up the server that you are targeting as a linked server on the server that has the database that the dataset is connected to originally." <- This is key: the query is still executing on the server specified in the original connection. This is a nice work around, but to answer the original question directly: No, you can't change the datasources at run time. Another workaround would be to define all the possible datasources and appropriate queries for each. Then you can select which dataset you display. (Other datasets won't be executed until they need to be displayed.)

Comment: This is a good solution except that I have literally hundreds of different databases on different servers. It is a lot of work to maintain all those linked servers. I think upgrading to SSRS 2005 or greater and using the expression based connection strings is the solution to my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've been doing it for so long I just assumed SSRS had always allowed this. In that case, I think the solution is to create a thin data processing extension as you suggest. We did this to query an ASP.Net MVC ReST API we created and while it isn't trivial, it isn't as difficult as you might think and there are some good examples on the net to get you started. As you are just passing your server and database as parameters and the SQL as the command text it would be fairly simple and is probably the way to go. I'd still set up servers and databases in a table for easy parameter selection.